# Swift - touchesBegan, touchesMoved not called after segue

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uistoryboardsegue, touchesbegan

I have a view controller before a game, where the user holds their finger on the screen for 3 seconds before it starts. The game requires their finger stays on the screen, so this ensures it is when the game starts. After the 3 seconds, the view controller that holds the full game is shown.

However, `touchesBegan:` and `touchesMoved:` are not called because the users finger was already on the screen before the view controller was shown.

Can I manually call `touchesBegan:` or `touchesMoved:`? Or is there some other way of doing this?

Comment: Is there strong reason you want to use touchesBegan and touchesMoved here? I doubt there is the way in your situation to use it (only in case if user remove fingers and tap again). Try other methods, maybe call them after viewWillAppear? As you pointed out, view was shown, so that method will be called.

Comment: Try using booleans , they may help